# Is “un-grown-up” a common, or not so common word?

Tags: contemporary-english

I came across a word, “un-grown-up” in Jeffery Archer’s fiction, “The Prodigal Daughter.”
In the scene, the heroine, Florentyna Rosnovski asks her governess if her father, the owner of a hotel empire, doesn’t love her mother any more:

> “Then why has Papa stopped coming home?” “That I can not explain, but
>   whatever his reasons, we must be very understanding and grown-up.”
>   said Miss Tredgold, brushing back a lock of hair that fallen over
>   Florentyna’s forehead. Florentyna **felt very un-grown-up** and wondered
>   if Saint Joan had been so unhappy when she lost her beloved France. –
>   P75.

The meaning of “un-grown-up” is obvious, but I don’t think I’ve ever seen the word before.

I consulted online CED, OED, Merriam-Webster, and Collins Cobuild English Dictionary at hand, none of which carries ‘ungrown’ or ‘un-grown-up.’

Even Google Ngram shows neither ‘ungrown’ nor ‘un-grown-up.’

Curiously enough however, Kenkyusha’s Readers English Japanese Dictionary published by a leading Japanese foreign language dictionary specialist publisher carries "ungrown" as an adjective meaning “not grown up, immature, or childish.”

Is “un-grown-up” a common, or not so common, or taken-for-granted word?

Comment: From the context of the excerpt, I'd venture to say that "un-grown-up" is a juxtaposed, though childish, contradiction to "grown-up".  It's not very common. (Not the down-voter!  I love your questions, Yoichi!)

Comment: The better word, found in dictionaries is **adolescent**

Comment: @mplungjan, _adolescent_ would not work in this case at all. The meaning, as Kristina pointed out, is a literal, binary opposite juxtaposed with _grown-up_, which _adolescent_ isn’t. A ‘proper’ way of phrasing it without coining nonce words, would be to say, “Florentyna felt _anything but grown-up_”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search returns a few headlines:

`Adam Sandler's un-'Grown Up' looks`

`Kids books, fun books, un-grownup kids books`

`Musings of an Un-Grown-Up`

`Never Neverland - Un-Grownup talk.`

`Unsuitable for Adults | games for the un-grownup`

I wouldn't say this *word* is "uncommon" but English is very flexible - and adding an 'un' on the front of anything will be easily understood and accepted.

--Ungrown has nothing to do with this word though -- this is simply just "grownup" + "un".